# Linux: how to display file within the same date

Tags: linux, grep, ls

so in linux, if I do this `ls -alth`, then it display all files inside a folders with the date of last modifications. I want to display files that last modify on a particular date. How do I achieve that. So I try this

```
ls -alth | cut -f7 -d " " | grep 2011-07-02
```

so display every thing -> then pipe to a parser -> then pipe the result at field 7, which is the date, to `grep` to filter down to the date that I want. Well the result is all

```
2011-07-02
2011-07-02
2011-07-02
...
```

**I want to see the file name.**

Comment: @AljoshaBre: man I am such an idiot. Can you make this into an answer so I can accept it. tyvm :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer

```
ls -alth | grep 2011-07-02
```

Answer (score 1):

(I am currently sitting on a windows machine, so the command syntax is just by memory)

You can use `find` for this:

```
find /your/dir -maxdepth 1 -mtime 2011-07-02 -print0 | xargs -0 ls -lath
```

Answer (score 1):

I advice to use

```
find -ctime 2
```

if you want to find files that were changed during the last 2 days or

```
find -cnewer test
```

If you are just interested in files that have a younger modification date than the file 'test'.

Answer (score 0):

grep without cutting, it would be rare false positive match; and if you want just the file name, cut at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You want to grep and then cut, although I would use nawk:

```
ls -alth | nawk '{for (i=8; i<=NF;i++) printf("%s ",$i); printf("\n")}'
```